# Click one li , add display block on span tag inside clicked li , and when clicked another do same for that and make display none to previous one

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
<li class="trigger">Menu One<span class="show_hide">Show Hide One</span></li>
<li class="trigger">Menu Two<span class="show_hide">Show Hide Two</span></li>
<li class="trigger">Menu Three<span class="show_hide">Show Hide Three</span></li>
```

When I click on the Menu One ,Show Hide One text will be appear and when I will click the second li then first one will be display none. But always the text Menu One,Menu Two,Menu Three will be visible. I have set display none to class="show_hide". Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It is hard to understand your question.

Comment: At first the text between span tag will be hidden. when I will click on li only that span will be visible and when I will click the second li, the first span will be hidden and second one will be visible

Comment: So you want to only show the span of the last clicked li???

Comment: Yes you are right @MCMXCII

Comment: My answer should do the trick then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, this should do the trick.

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('.trigger span').addClass('show_hide');
    $(this).children('span').removeClass('show_hide');
})
```